# This actually works but is there another way to loop?

Tags: php, arrays, session, loops, for-loop

```
 // Loop $key

$key = count($_SESSION['imageURL']);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $key; $i++) {

    echo $_SESSION['imageURL'][$i];

    echo $_SESSION['clubURL'][$i];

}
```

Comment: not counting the $_SESSION['imageURL']

Comment: Apart from the obvious error that you start at `1` (array indexes start at `0`, this seems pretty good. Are there any guarantee, though, that `$_SESSION['clubURL']` contains (at least) as many elements as `$_SESSION['imageURL']`? Consider `$key = min(count($_SESSION['imageURL']), count($_SESSION['clubURL']));` if this is an issue.

Comment: foreach($_SESSION['imageURL'] as $imgURL)

Comment: in some cases $_SESSION['clubURL'] will not contains as many elements as $_SESSION['imageURL']

Comment: @Carlos Martins In that case just count them both and use the lowest value (shortest array). See my comment above or answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several other ways:

[**`foreach`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach ($_SESSION['imageURL'] as $key => $image) {
    echo $image;
    echo $_SESSION['clubURL'][$key];
}
```

[**`while`**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php)

```
while (list ($key, $image) = each ($_SESSION['imageURL']) {
    echo $image;
    echo $_SESSION['clubURL'][$key];
}
```

[**`do..while`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php)

```
if (count($_SESSION['imageURL']) {
    do {
        echo current($_SESSION['imageURL']);
        echo $_SESSION['clubURL'][key($_SESSION['imageURL'])];
    } while (next($_SESSION['clubURL']));
}
```

Personally, I prefer your technique with the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($_SESSION['imageURL'] as $k=>$image)
{
   echo $image;
   echo $_SESSION['clubURL'][$k];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `foreach`. Should look somehow like this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['imageURL'] as $image) {
    echo $image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to only go as far as *both* arrays hold values (see OP's comment on question):

```
// $shortest holds the length of the *shortest* array, i.e., iteration
// only goes as far as both arrays have indexes.
$shortest = min(count($_SESSION['imageURL']), count($_SESSION['clubURL']));
for ($i = 0; $i < $shortest; $i++) {
    echo $_SESSION['imageURL'][$i];
    echo $_SESSION['clubURL'][$i];
}
```

**Note**
This only works if the two arrays are "parallel", i.e., the n'th value of `$_SESSION['imageURL']` matches the n'th value of `$_SESSION['clubURL']` until the end of any (or both) of the arrays.